# Eigen: Replicate (broadcast) by rows

Tags: optimization, eigen

I'd like to replicate each row of a matrix `M` without any copy occurring (i.e. by creating a view):

```
0  1          0  1
2  3    ->    0  1
              2  3
              2  3
```

- `M.rowwise().replicate(n)` is a shorcut for `M.replicate(1,n)` which seems kind of useless.
- The following snippet does a copy, and cannot work if `M` is an expression.

```
    Eigen::Index rowFactor = 2;
    Eigen::MatrixXi M2 = Eigen::Map(M.data(), 1, M.size()).replicate(rowFactor, 1);
    M2.resize(M.rows()*rowFactor, M.cols()) ;
```

- In some situation, I may use the intermediate view `Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXi>(M.data(), 1, M.size()).replicate(rowFactor, 1)` by reshaping the other operands, but that's not very satisfying.

Is there a proper way to achieve this broadcast view?

Answer (score 3):

What you want is essentially a [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) with a matrix of ones. You can use the (unsupported) [KroneckerProduct module](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/group__KroneckerProduct__Module.html) for that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/KroneckerProduct>

int main() {
    Eigen::Matrix2i M; M << 0, 1, 2, 3;
    std::cout << Eigen::kroneckerProduct(M, Eigen::Vector2i::Ones()) << '\n';
}
```

Being 'unsupported' means that the API of the module is not guaranteed to be stable (though this module has not changed since its introduction, I think).

Comment: Nice solution, although a temporary vector and multiplications are used. I must check whether this product is done lazily.

Comment: The `Vector2i::Ones()` will not be explicitly generated. There will indeed happen a multiplication, but I'd be confident that at least for integers the compiler will be able to optimize that away. If you want to be 100% certain that no multiplication occurs, have a look at the implementation of KroneckerProduct.

Comment: You're right. Even the dynamic version `VectorXi::Ones(size)` will return an optimized 'constant' Vector.