# Eigen rowwise replicate

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

How to do rowwise replication in Eigen?

This replicate matrix N times:

```
MatrixXd m(3,2);
m << 1,2,3,4,5,6;
std::cout << "m:" << std::endl;
std::cout << m << std::endl;

MatrixXd m1 = m.replicate(2, 1);
std::cout << "m1:" << std::endl;
std::cout << m1 << std::endl;

m:
1 2
3 4
5 6

m1:
1 2
3 4
5 6
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

But I need:

```
m2:
1 2
1 2
3 4
3 4
5 6
5 6
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eigen: Replicate (broadcast) by rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466391/eigen-replicate-broadcast-by-rows)